# Blackberry listfield

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I'm wondering if anyone has come across any sample code for creating a listField that has clickable rows.

I'm using Blackberry 5.0 API and I need to create of table of clickable rows. When the row is clicked then the user will be brought to a new screen showing more content.

Have looked around but I haven't found any good examples of using a ListField (any other component using the 5.0 API) to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override `protected boolean navigationClick(int, int)` to something like:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    super.navigationClick(status, time);
    fieldChangeNotify(1);
}
```

And then attach a `FieldChangeListener` to it, and make sure you `fieldChanged(int context)` method checks for `context==1` to listen for clicks. You might want to head to the [BB Java Development forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev) for another resource, as this questions and many others have been answered on there and it might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks . Got advice of the BB forum to use ListField and I have this working now, it seems to be working o.k.